# How to use expect and git clone?

Tags: git, expect

I'm trying to clone from my private git repository using expect to enter the password in one line.

I'm trying something like:

> expect -c 'spawn git clone user@**.**.**.**:/var/.../repository.git/; expect "(yes/no)?"; send "yes\n"; expect "password:"; send "my_password\n";interact'

But, it doesn't work. 
What am I doing wrong? How can I fix the command line above?

Thanks, Arshavdki Alexander

Comment: The reason why expect doesn't work as expected, is because ssh is *correctly* writing directly to the terminal, rather than stdout or stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you just use something more secure than a password and simplify your life?

An ssh key with no password will be *significantly* more secure and not prompt at all.

If it must be 100% self-contained, then consider making the script output the SSH key, use it once, then remove it. (That should leave your security situation unchanged: the password is effectively in the script, which is acceptable for you.)

```
# Output SSH key for no-password login. (Could use mktemp instead)
cat > /tmp/ssh_key.$$ <<EOT
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
blahblahblah
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
EOT

# Make a SSH wrapper to do the right thing
cat > /tmp/git_ssh.$$ <<EOT
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /tmp/ssh_key.$$ "$@"
EOT
chmod +x /tmp/git_ssh.$$
export GIT_SSH=/tmp/git_ssh.$$

# Done!
git clone user@host:path/to/repo

# Cleanup
rm -f /tmp/git_ssh.$$ /tmp/ssh_key.$$
```

Yes the script looks unwieldy but (modulo bugs) it is self-contained pretty useful for automation.

Comment: The problem is that I'm writing a deployment script and this should run from a script.

Comment: ...all the more reason to make it more secure and automated, right?  Perhaps you should check out the github guides for ssh?  http://help.github.com/set-up-git-redirect/

Comment: Can you please answer my question?

Comment: I fail to understand how I did not.  I do this exact thing myself.

Comment: @Dustin, I took the liberty of adding a hacky, buggy shell script that will doubtless tarnish your reputation as a good coder :) @alexarsh hopefully this is at least partially helpful or can give you ideas for alternatives.

Comment: Heh.  Sure, but I'd just reference the key from `~/.ssh/config` if I needed a different one and let ssh do the normal thing.  I typically just use the default key, though and then no additional password stuff is needed.

Comment: Seriously, using ssh keys is the only *sensible* option.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid using expect by directly entering password in the url

```
git clone https://username:password@github.com/username/repository.git
```

Please note - this causes your password to be stored in the .git files, making this a permanently insecure option.

However, you can leave out the password:

`git clone https://username@github.com/username/repository.git`

git will ask you for password and it will not be saved in .git/config nor in your bash history

Comment: Unfortunately doing this causes your password to be stored in the .git files, making this a permanently insecure option. This should not be used.