# Automatically feed input to Linux command line

Tags: linux, git, bash, ubuntu

If I have a linux command that prompts for 2 or more input, how can these inputs be passed to the prompt by defining it in the command line? Is there something you can add behind the command to do this?

In the example below, how can you run the command and pass it the username and password without having to type it in when the system asks for them?

**Example command that asks for username and password**

```
git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

*Just an example, please don't suggest doing the git clone using ssh instead of http, or that its insecure to expose the password in the command*

Comment: **man expect** ... if it's not installed:  **sudo apt-get install expect**

Comment: Note that the specific command is relevant because some use standard input and output (which usually can be redirected by the usual shell means) while others, like ssh used by git, uses the terminal. I'm almost sure there are "terminals" conceived to support your usage (and maybe expect can do that) but it's always a bad crutch. Which is the reason that almost all particular interactive programs (e.g., vi) have non-interactive counterparts (e.g., sed) and  people answer with "but don't do that" in every particular case (like git).

Comment: Ah, [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1610065/failed-attempt-to-expect-and-send-in-an-expect-script-in-mingw) is an instruction how to use expect for that. Ending, predictably, in "but don't do that" ;-). So this is a dup but on another SE.

Answer (score 4):

The "expect" package is built for this kind of thing.
If you install it, check out "autoexpect".

Example:

```sh
autoexpect
# Output: autoexpect started, file is script.exp

# Login with user/pass with ssh - just to test
ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no myuser@myhost
<type-password>
<command>
<command>
exit

# Now exit once more to exit autoexpect
# Output: autoexpect done, file is script.exp
```

Next thing is to edit script.exp and clean it up.
There is loads of documentation on this.

Comment: Hmm... A comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531241/how-to-use-expect-and-git-clone) seems to suggest that expect wouldn't work here because ssh uses the terminal device instead of stdin/stdout. I'm not sure expect can do that. It may though because those are the interesting cases. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3):

I want the bounty, and I can't close as dup because the answer is on a different SE.

Quoting [the answer on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1610065/failed-attempt-to-expect-and-send-in-an-expect-script-in-mingw):

Use the program `expect` which has been conceived for exactly your needs which were felt already by users in a land before our time, given that its [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) states:

> Connect to another network or BBS (e.g., MCI Mail, **CompuServe**).

Compuserve, was that before or after the French Revolution? Anyway.

```
spawn "git clone ssh://git@domain.com/myproject.git"
expect "Enter passphrase for key..." { send "myPassword\r" }
read -p "enter..."
```

Perhaps the last line is superfluous.

[*Ceterum censeo*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carthago_delenda_est): Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

*NOTE: Git requires you to use git token instead of password.*

> empty is an utility that provides a simple interface to execute and/or
> interact with processes under pseudo-terminal sessions.
>
> This tool is definitely useful in programming of shell scripts that
> are sed to communicate with interactive programs like telnet or FTP.
>
> In some cases empty can be a substitution for  TCL/expect or other
> similar programming tools.

Copy the bellow code into your script file.

Make it executable and run the script by providing the following argument from the command line (as you asked for it):

- Git repo URI (as the first argument)
- Git username (as the second argument)
- Git user token (as the third argument)

Example:

Assuming your script file name is: `git_clone.sh`:

```sh
./git_clone.sh  <GIT_REPO_URI>  <GIT_USERNAME>  <GIT_USER_TOKEN>
```

```sh
#!/bin/bash
git_repo="${1}"
git_user="${2}"
git_token="${3}"

empty -f -i in.fifo -o out.fifo -pempty.pid  git clone  

empty -w -i out.fifo -o in.fifo sername  "${git_user}\n"
empty -w -i out.fifo -o in.fifo assword  "${git_token}\n"

exit 0
```

For more details about `empty` refer to its manual:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/empty.1.html

*Note: `empty` command needs to be available by installing `empty-expect` package.*

To install on Ubuntu 18.04 or 16.04 you can run:

```sh
add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
apt update;
apt install -y empty-expect
```

*### Update: To install `empty-expect` package in Ubuntu 20.04 you may use the Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) `universe` repository by running the following commands:*

```sh
echo 'deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic universe' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bionic-universe.list
apt update
apt install -y empty-expect
```

Comment: `empty: command not found` Why am I getting this error?

Comment: @ChitturiSaiSuman,  please make sure that you have empty-expect package installed. Example how to install on Ubuntu-based distributions, run:
sudo apt update;
sudo apt install empty-expect

Comment: Hi, it seems like the 'empty-expect' package is not available on `Ubuntu 20.04 LTS` (Ubuntu Focal).

Comment: @ChitturiSaiSauman, I don't have Ubuntu 20.04 but I'd suggest the following: google it, and share the output of what you get when you run the commands in my previous comment. Thank you.

Comment: ```
sudo apt install -y empty-expect
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package empty-expect
```

Comment: @ChitturiSaiSuman I've tested and updated my answer. To install `empty-expect` package in ubuntu 20.04 you may use the ubuntu 18.04 (bionic) `universe` repository. Please vote up my answer if you find it usefull.

Answer (score 1):

### Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), you could use `script`

`script` will produce a ***tty*** you could interact with under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), using `coproc`. This could be done without de need of `expect`:

> ```
> NAME
>       script - make typescript of terminal session
>
> SYNOPSIS
>       script [options] [file]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>       script  makes  a  typescript  of everything on your terminal session.
>       The terminal data are stored in raw form to the log file and information
>       about timing to another (optional) structured log file. The timing
>       log file is necessary to replay the session later by scriptreplay(1) and to
>       store additional information about the session.
> ```

#### Demo

```bash
coproc script -f /dev/null
```

Could return:

```
[1] 2103233
```

This initiate a subshel, you coul interact with,

```bash
while read -t 0 -u ${COPROC[0]};do
    read -t .02 -ru ${COPROC[0]} line
    echo "$line"
done
```

should produce something like:

```
Script started, output log file is 'typescript'.
user@hostname:~$
```

Then

```bash
echo >&${COPROC[1]} ssh user@target
while [ ! "$line" ] || [ "${line//*password*}" ];do
    read -t .02 -ru ${COPROC[0]} line
    echo "$line"
done
echo >&${COPROC[1]} TheStrongPasswordInClear
while [ ! "$line" ] || [ "${line//*\$*}" ];do
        read -t .02 -ru ${COPROC[0]} line
    echo "$line"
done
```

There, you could see a lot of lines like

```
ssh user@target
user@target's password:

Linux target 5.00.0-0-amd64 # Distro ...
issue.net content...
Last login: Sun Dec 19 12:23:37 2021 from somewhere

user@target:~$
```

From there, you could:

```bash
getres() {
    while read -t 0 -u ${COPROC[0]};do
        read -t .02 -ru ${COPROC[0]} line
        echo "$line"
    done
}

echo >&${COPROC[1]} uptime
getres
```

```
uptime
12:38:38 up 21 days,  3:52, 122 users,  load average: 3.20, 2.19, 1.59
```

And finaly

```bash
echo >&${COPROC[1]} exit  
getres
```

```
exit
logout
Connection to target closed.
```

## Full executable [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) script

This run under `bash 5.1.4(1)-release`, on `GNU/Debian Linux 11.2`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
line='' Debug=false

exp1() { # Collect input by bytes, until expected string (1st arg)
    local char attended="*${1}"
    line=
    IFS= read -d '' -ru "${COPROC[0]}" -t 2 -n 1 line
    while IFS= read -d '' -ru "${COPROC[0]}" -t .02 -n 1 char;do
        line+="$char"
        case "$line" in
            *$1 ) $Debug && echo "GOOD ${line@A} match ${attended@A}"
                  return 0;;
        esac
    done
    $Debug && echo "BAD: ${line@A}"
    return 1
}
expect() { # expect <Expected String after> <Command> [switches] [args]
    local expectStr="$1" maxErr=5
    shift
    [ "$1" ] && echo >&"${COPROC[1]}" "$@"
    while ! exp1 "${expectStr}" && ((maxErr--));do sleep .2;done
}
getAns() { # getAns <ResultVar> <Command> [switches] [args]
    local -n res=$1
    res=''
    shift
    local req="$*" maxErr=5
    echo >&"${COPROC[1]}" "$req"
    exp1 "$req"$'\r\n'
    while ! exp1 "$ " && ((maxErr--));do res+="$line" ;sleep .2 ;done
    res+="${line%$'\r\n'*}"
}
```

```bash
read -rp target:\  target
read -rsp password:\  pass
echo "${pass//?/*}"

coproc TERM=none script -f /dev/null
IFS= read -ru "${COPROC[0]}" line &&
    $Debug && echo "1 >>> $line <<<"

expect '$ '
expect 'password: ' ssh "$target"
expect '$ ' "$pass"

getAns ut uptime
# shellcheck disable=SC2154 # referenced but not assigned (ut ??)
echo "${ut@A}"

expect '$ '  exit
```

Run sample:

```
target: user@target
password: ************
ut=' 11:06:20 up 5 days, 2:19, 22 users, load average: 0.74, 1.13, 1.27'
```

You may found this script on my site: [expectScr.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/expectScr.sh), or [expectScr.sh.txt](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/expectScr.sh.txt), ready to be *sourced*.

Comment: Answer edited: Here is now a full executable script! On my site: [expectScr.sh](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/expectScr.sh), or [expectScr.sh.txt](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/expectScr.sh.txt).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```sh
{
  echo user
  echo pass
} | git clone https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

[`ref`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands)

Comment: This will work if `git` reads the password from stdin, but not if it reads it from `/dev/tty` (as many password-prompting applications do). I don't know offhand how `git` works in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on why you want to do this, you may want to explore ways to use github repositories without passwords:

https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys

Answer (score 0):

Don't know have you tried this or not. But this is useful in case we execute any sudo cmd and needs to enter a password. You can try this in your case.

But I think you have to provide a username at least.

For example :

```
sudo -S <<< "password" sudo yum -y update
```

In your case, it should be like :

```
sudo -S <<< {password} git clone https://github.com/{username}/repo.git
```